# Java OpenGL drawing only visible textures

Tags: opengl, render, tile

I'm trying to create a small 2D game within LWJGL however, large maps drop the frame rate from around 3000 to about 15. I know this is mainly caused because it's drawing every tile on the screen even though you can only see a small portion of them. I'd like to know how to find which tiles would be visible and only print them to the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_surface_determination#Culling_and_VSD), one of the best known techniques is `frustum culling`. Generally, you define a bounding volume and test if an object lies within it.

For example, in 2D you could define a rectangle (identical to your window/viewport) and for each object (tile/sprite/whatever) define a bounding box. A circle is an easy bounding box to test, but a rectangle would work as well.

Then you simply test if your object's bounding box and the viewport rectangle intersect. If so, draw it, otherwise, don't.

Also see [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14713/culling-for-a-2d-platformer-game) answer on another SE site for more detailed information about 2d culling.

Comment: Thank you :D I'll add add this in as soon as possible, thanks for the help!